# I Got a Permission Error After Installing This Game

Tags: python, operating-system, file-handling, storing-data

I have this function from a game class:

```
def store_data(self):
    if self.score > self.best_score:
        with open("best_score.txt", "w") as file:
            msg = f"BEST SCORE: {self.score}"
            file.write(msg)
            file.close()
```

I want to store the best_score in this txt file (if there is a better way of storing data in python you're welcome to correct me, thank you)
I finished the game and I used pyinstaller + NSIS to get a single file, and of course, I installed it on my device, before installing there is no issue, but after installing and running the game from my local desk C:\\ I got this error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'best_score.txt'
```

So please, could you help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user executing the code doesn't have the required permission. Maybe you're running the code in a directory which requires admin privilege (and since you do not provide a path, Python tries to save the file in that dir) or maybe another user created the file.

I recommend storing the result in (a sub-path of) the user's home directory, e.g.

```
import os

USER_HOME: str = os.path.expanduser("~")
with open(f"{USER_HOME}/best_score.txt", "w") as file:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Thank you so much @niko, These couple of lines solved my problem and taught me new IMPORTANT information. Have a good day!